# Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side .?

Tags: android-widget

I'm trying to play video by videoview from streamURL, I recieved Logcat error :"Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side", I have added Androidmanifest Internet permision, what is the error in stream URL.?,this is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://s3/phimbo/hanquoc/2012/12/Horse.Doctor/Horse.Doctor.E02.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: I dont want to duplicate a deleted answer so.. the Issue I had was the INTERNET permission, add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the manifest

Comment: I got it, have no bug here, I still have a wrong video URL

Answer (score 3):

"Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side" is not an error message, but a debug message from the MediaPlayer. Logcat always says this when trying to play a network video stream. As for your problem, it looks like your rtsp url is invalid since 's3' is not a complete domain. Have you tried the IP address in your url instead? Can you play the video with VLC (from http://www.videolan.org)? I see nothing wrong with your code except the url.

Comment: I get the same error message, but: 
1. the video works.
2. it is being played from the internal storage (getFilesDir()).

How, in this case, is this only a debug message?

Answer (score 0):

The some problem but only on HTC. We have disabled audio on server side and it is working now. Some problem with audio codec i guess.